# Can I modify the text of links within the type declaration inside @property tags in JSDoc?

Tags: jsdoc

I am using the following syntax in JSDoc to link to type definitions within property definitions:

```
@property {module:a/b/c/type[]} propName propDescription
```

This works, but it uses the entire text within the curly braces as the type name in the generated documentation. For example, the above line results in generated doc that looks something like:

```
| propName | Array.<module:a/b/c/type> | propDescription |
```

Is there some way to do this but only have the actual type name displayed in the link? I want it to look like this:

```
| propName | Array.type | propDescription |
```

but still have "type" link to the documentation describing that type.

I have been unable to find any documentation related to this type of linking; I only found the current syntax by searching StackOverflow (mainly from this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29622478/how-to-make-link-of-method-parameter-type-in-jsdoc))